Finding Species-specific Parameters for RIBBIT (opensoundscape)
I am trying to find waterfrog (Pelophylax) calls in my audiofiles. While using RIBBIT I need the following parameters:

signal band
noise band
pulse rate range (min/max)
number of samples per spectrogram window
overlap percentage (not number of samples) of spectrogram windows
length of analysis window, in seconds

Maybe someone can help me with those parameters

what do you mean by "help me"? what the parameters mean, or what the values should be? IMHO, is that not the essence of research to determine these values?

Yes, to elaborate on WMXZ's point: the nature of a good stack exchange question involves 1) being clear about what it is being asked, and 2) demonstrating what solutions have already been tried (and if possible explaining why they weren't suitable). Revising the question to address these issues would increase the likelihood of a helpful response.
